# Can't add nodes in my linked list (java)

Tags: java, linked-list, nodes

I've been working on my add method for a couple of hours now and seem to have hit a roadblock. My method is supposed to search through every node in the list to see if there is a matching employee number and if there isn't, add the object in order of employee number.

Unfortunately I cant even seem to add a node to the beginning or end of my list. I think I understand the logic. I have to search through my list for find where I want the node, then all I have to do is have the new node's link point the already existing one. I think that I'm either not creating the nodes properly or not linking them properly. Every time I try to test my code though, only one node appears in my list.

```
    import java.util.*;

public class HumanResources
{

    private EmployeeNode first;
    employee data = new employee();

    private class EmployeeNode
    {

        //data members of employeenode
        private EmployeeNode link;
        employee data = new employee();


        private EmployeeNode()
        {
            data = null;
            link = null;
        }

        private EmployeeNode (employee emp)
        {
            data = emp;
            link = null;
        }


    }


    public EmployeeNode search (employee search)
    {
        EmployeeNode current = first;

        if (first == null)
        { return null;}

        while((present != null) && (present.data != search))
        {
            present = present.link;

        }

        return present;


    }

    private EmployeeNode nextInList(EmployeeNode x)
    {
        return x.link;
    }



   public boolean isEmpty()
   {
      return ( first == null );
   } // end of isEmpty()

    public HumanResources()
    {
        first = null;
    }

    public HumanResources ( employee x)
    {
        this.data = x;
    }






    public boolean addEmployee( employee emp)
    {

        EmployeeNode current = new EmployeeNode();
        current = first;

            if (current == null)
            {
                first = new EmployeeNode(emp);
                return true;

            }
            else
            {
                while(current.link != null)
                {
                    EmployeeNode temp = new EmployeeNode();
                    temp.data = emp;
                    temp.link = current;
                }
                return true;
            }
    }

    public Employee findEmployee(String EmpNumber)
    {
        EmployeeNode current = first;
        if(first == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        else{
            while (current != null)
            {






    public String toString()
    {
        EmployeeNode display;
        display = first;
        String temp = "";

        while(display != null)
        {
            temp += display.data + "\n";
            display = display.link;

        }
        return temp;
    }


}
```

And here is my employee class

```
import java.util.*;
/**
This class manipulate information relating to employees
*/
public class employee {

    private String empNumber;
    private String name;
    private String department;
    private double salary;
    /**
    Zero parameter constructor that sets the values to null
    */
    public employee()
    {
        empNumber = null;
        name = null;
        department = null;
        salary = 0.0;
    }

    /**
    Four parameter constructor to initialize the data members to the give values

    @param kempnumber Employee's ID number
    @param kname Employee's name
    @param kdepartment Employee's department name
    @param ksalary Employee's salary
    */
    public employee(String kempnumber, String kname, String kdepartment, double ksalary)
    {
        empNumber = kempnumber;
        department=kdepartment ;
        name = kname;
        salary = ksalary;

    }
    /**
    copy constructor
    */
    public employee (employee copy)
    {
        empNumber = copy.empNumber;
        name = copy.name;
        department = copy.department;
        salary = copy.salary;

    }
    /**
    Four parameter constructor to set data members to given value
    @param kname Employee's name
    @param kdepartment Employee's department name
    @param ksalary Employee's salary
    */
    public void setEmployee(String kempnumber, String kname, String kdepartment, double ksalary)
    {
        empNumber = kempnumber;
        department=kdepartment ;
        name = kname;
        salary = ksalary;
    }



    public String getEmpNumber() {
        return empNumber;
    }

    public void setEmpNumber(String empNumber) {
        this.empNumber = empNumber;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDepartment() {
        return department;
    }

    public void setDepartment(String department) {
        this.department = department;
    }

    public double getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }

    public void setSalary(double salary)
    {
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
            return (empNumber + " " + name + " " + department + " " +salary);
    }


    public boolean equals(employee compareto) {

        int firstemployee = Integer.parseInt(empNumber);
        int secondemployee = Integer.parseInt(compareto.empNumber);

        if (firstemployee == secondemployee) {

            return true;
        }

        else {

            return false;
        }

    }


    public int compareTo(employee compareto)
    {
        int less = -1;
        int same = 0;
        int more = 1;
        int firstemployee = Integer.parseInt(empNumber);
        int secondemployee = Integer.parseInt(compareto.empNumber);

            if(firstemployee > secondemployee)
            {
                return more;
            }

            else if(firstemployee == secondemployee)
            {
                return same;
            }

            else
            {
                return less;
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: `while(current.link != null)
                {
                    EmployeeNode temp = new EmployeeNode();
                    temp.data = emp;
                    temp.link = current;
                }
` - what do you currently think this does?

Comment: The while loop goes through the entire list until the end. Temp is the node I want to insert in the list. And I thought that temp.link = current would be how I would connect the temp node to the other node in the list?

Comment: Why do you think the while loop goes through the entire list until the end? What you have is "while the first node has a link (i.e. the list is at least two nodes long), create new nodes and don't do anything with them (so they eventually get garbage collected)"

Comment: Okay, so i change the condition to (current != null) and at the end of the while loop also add current = current.link to keep it cycling through the loop? Also since my nodes are created the problem is that I'm not linking them correctly with each other?

Comment: Run it in your head. The loop does nothing like what you think it does.

Comment: Thanks, I realized the while loop was unnecessary at the moment thanks to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the addEmployee method, if you are adding to the front of the list you shouldn't need a while loop at all. Your 'first' variable is presumably maintaining a reference to the front of the loop, so all you need to do is create the employee, update the links and point 'first' towards it. Something like this...

```
public boolean addEmployee( employee emp){

    if (first == null)  {
        first = new EmployeeNode(emp);
        return true;
    }
    else {  // first must != null
        EmployeeNode temp = new EmployeeNode(emp); //create the new employee
        temp.link = first; // link the new employee to the old employee at the front of the list

        first = temp; //update the new front of list to be the new employee
        return true;
    }
}
```

Keep in mind though if you want to add it to the *end* of the list, you will need a while loop to search through the list and find the end before creating the new employee and updating the links.

If your getting confused with the links, try stepping through the code and drawing out the nodes with lines to represent the links to help get you used to visualising the linked list.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I think I finally managed to clear it up in my head a bit.